# Code generated by flex won't print to the console

Tags: flex-lexer, lex

I'm experimenting with flex to try to gain a better understanding of how it works. I have this in the lex (.l) file:

```
%option noyywrap

%%
"a"   printf("Found an \"a\"");

%%

int main()
{
   printf("This is working");
   return 0;
}
```

Ignoring the single rule for now (unless it's somehow the cause) I want to know why the printf statement in the main() function isn't doing anything. After digging through the generated lex.yy.c file, I suspect the line

```
yyout = stdout;
```

might be the cause, although I can't say why (and I couldn't find anything when searching for why flex does this)

I'm hoping to understand not only what this means in terms of C code, but *why* flex does this. It seems to be either supressing or redirecting the output (to the yacc code maybe?). I would appreciate any explanations or links to some information.

(Unless this is just my C code being somehow broken)

Comment: If you don't call `yylex`, the lexer will have no impact on the running of your program :-)

Comment: @rici check my comment on the below answer (such a stupid mistake) the print statement in the main function works fine without calling yylex. Could you clarify what wouldn't work if I don't?

Comment: The main issue that people encounter is that the line printed without a newline isn't actually output until later, when you output a newline (or close stdout). This can fool you into thinking that an error (like a segfault) occurred much earlier than it actually did, because abrupt termination stops the program before stdout is flushed and you never see the output. So debugging output and logging should always be newline terminated and/or directed to an unbuffered output stream.

Comment: yylex really has nothing to do with this. If you don't call it, it didn't happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `puts` instead of `printf` then  a newline will be appended automatically for you. There's no point in using `printf` to print a constant string which doesn't include formatted conversions.

You could do that yourself, of course, by changing it to

```
printf("This is working\n")
```

or:

```
printf("%s\n", "This is working.");
```

Or even better:

```
fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "This is working.");
```

(See below.)

If you don't output a newline, your output will probably just stay in the stdio buffer (although it should be flushed when stdout is closed). Also, some IDEs behave badly when the last bit of output is not terminated with a newline.  (Swallowing the characters is a common symptom.) All in all, it's best to follow the following guidelines.

In general:

- You should always end printed lines with new lines.
- You should be aware of the consequences of `stdout` line buffering, which is that in common cases, not terminating output to `stdout` means that it won't be presented right away.
- And you should get in the habit of using `stderr` instead of `stdout` for logging messages, even if they are not strictly speaking errors, leaving `stdout` for the processed output of your program (in case you want to pipe the output into another utility). Unlike `stdout`, `stderr` is (by default) usually unbuffered, so output is presented immediately. (But you should still put a newline at the end, rather than leaving the cursor dangling in the middle of the line.)

  `fputs` does not automatically write the newline, by the way. But it's still better than `fprintf` in the case of literal strings.

Comment: Oh no. I cannot believe myself. I named the output file "test". when I tried to run it, I was actually running the unix command "test". Unbelievable. I renamed it and tried running it again and everything worked.

Comment: @Hayden. Ah, yes, that was another possibility. But my answer stands. :-) This is a good time to develop good habits.

Comment: Hopefully this is ok to ask (since it isn't related to the original question) but I was also trying to test the rule I wrote, but it won't print anything when I pass a text file containing some a's to the program. Is that not how lex programs work? And yes, I added a newline to the end :)

Comment: @hayden: Yes, the scanner should print the message. Make sure that you actually did pass it the text you think you did, and make sure that your logging message is newline-terminated :-) Also, the default rule also causes any unrecognised characters to be echoed to yyout (or stdout if yyout is NULL). Oh, and you do have to call yylex() to get the scanner to do something.

Comment: ok so, the program (testprogram) is running in "interactive" mode seemingly, it lets me input text and prints the string when encountering an "a". But I tried passing a text file (input_test.txt) containing "aaa" and a newline. Running the command "./testprogram input_test.txt" just enters this interactive mode. Another silly mistake?

Comment: @Hayden: What did you do to process the command line, open the indicated file, and hand it to yylex? (If you do nothing, `yyout` will be NULL and `yylex()` will read from `stdin`.)

Comment: If you don't want to do all that work (although it's not really hard), you can redirect: `./testprogram < input_test.txt`

Comment: Well, I've learned two things today. First, I should do more research to avoid silly mistakes. Second, many unexpected things can go wrong. I know how to process the command line and read the file, but not how to pass it to yylex. I guess I'll look that up. Thank you very much for your help and patience, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Also, I tried the redirect thing, it did indeed work. Thanks again.

Comment: `yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");` is pretty easy.

Comment: And a little light reading: http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/index.html#SEC_Contents (Actually, it's not bad, and it's a lot more informative than the bad examples you find on the internet.)